# Python script to run in background while capturing screenshots

Tags: python, linux, debian

I created some python code to capture screenshots if certain site is visited.
When i run my code from the terminal, it runs fine and gives output. It does not to seem to work when set as a cron job or startup script. What could be wrong? Complains of inability to start display but how can that be sorted? The code is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import time
import subprocess
def get_current_status(netss):
    netss = subprocess.check_output(“ss -rt”, shell=True)
    if “facebook” in netss:
        out_put = subprocess.check_output(‘import -window root “/home/user/test/new_$(date +%F-%N).png”‘, shell=True)
        time.sleep(3)
    elif “youtube” in netss:
        out_put = subprocess.check_output(‘import -window root “/home/user/test/new_$(date +%F-%N).png”‘, shell=True)

     else:
        print(“Not yet time to capture”)

def main():
    get_current_status(“netss”)
while True:
    main()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are getting? Could it be because the display is asleep when the cron job tries to run?

Comment: The exact error says it cannot get Display when it is time for image capture.
You can try that code on your machine and realize it runs well in terminal but not so when set as a cronjob or to run as a service. When set to run as a service using "update-rd.rc command defaults", where command is a shell script calling it, it gets errors of display.
What do you mean display asleep? In testing mode, you realize the interval of capture is very short hence display not asleep.

Comment: I got it running yesterday. I had to create a separate bash shell script that gets called by the python script. The bash script is the one that captures the screenshot, It uses xwd and states the display to be captured. It looks like this; #!/bin/bash export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/xwd -display :0.0 -root -out file_name

Comment: It also works pretty well if the xwd command runs from the python script directly as long as the display argument is indicated for the user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I got it sorted out using subprocess.getoutput in python3 and setting DISPLAY environment within the python script. You can as well run this python script as a cronjob. I developed this when i was in the process of getting gr.ounded in "classes and objects of python" Look at the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import os
if not 'DISPLAY' in os.environ:
    os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ":0"

class NewCapture:
    command = subprocess.getoutput("sudo ss -nt state established dst :443")
    file_name = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S" +".png")
    grab = ""
    def funct_capture(self):

        if ":443" in self.command:

            self.grab = ImageGrab.grab_to_file("/home/user/test/%s" % self.file_name)

        else:
            pass

firstcommand = NewCapture()
firstcommand.funct_capture()
```